# Warning: Attempt to present <SLTwitterComposeViewController: 0x233141c0> on <MainController: 0x2083ebb0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am receiving this error when trying to post an image to Twitter using the following code, cannot think what I am doing wrong any ideas for how to solve?;

```
- (void)PostToTwitter

    {   
        UIImage* pxImage = [[self GetResultImage] retain];

        TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

        [twitter setInitialText:@"Twitter Pic"];
        [twitter addImage:pxImage];

        FaceAppDelegate* app = (FaceAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [app.mainCtrl presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:NULL];

        twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res)
        {
            if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"You have posted successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
            else if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancelled" message:@"You have cancelled posting to Twitter." delegate:NULL cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
            [app.mainCtrl dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        };

        [pxImage release];

    }
```

Comment: I means that the `app.mainCtrl` view controller isn't displayed at the time you try to present the Twitter controller.

Comment: @rmaddy, plus one for a good answer, although in the form of comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your view isn't presented. Try to use app.window.rootViewController, not property mainContr.